# Can I make component parameter required when building a custom Blazor component?

Tags: c#, blazor

When I try to build a Blazor component I can define parameters for it like this:

```
@code {

   [Parameter]
   public string MyString { get; set; }

}
```

My question is can I make this parameter required so that, when component is used, the project will not build unless I provide the specified parameter? Is this something I should even be worried about? I suppose I could handle any invalid values in component initialization by maybe throwing an exception if the value is not provided like this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyString)) {
       // throw an exception here...
    }
}
```

but is that the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**.NET 6 and newer**

This can be accomplished with the `[EditorRequired]` attribute. Example:

```
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This will give an IDE warning to consumers of components that parameters are missing if their parameters are not supplied.

**Before .NET 6**

Currently, you’ll have to do exactly as you said.

Comment: Yup that's it, I'm not sure how I did not find this github issue but I'm glad you pointed it out.

Comment: C#11 and .NET 7 introduced the required modifier. Strange that in Blazor you can still skip a parameter even when you mark it as required. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required

Comment: @Pawel I thought the same and opened this issue. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44974

Answer (score 7):

I like to combine `[EditorRequired]` with an initial value of `null!`.

```
[Parameter, EditorRequired]
public string MyString { get; set; } = null!;
```

Technically, the value will be null before `OnInitialized()` runs, such as in the constructor. Still, it's more convenient than having to treat it as possibly null everywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

We've found that adding this to `.csproj` allows us to treat the warning as build errors.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  <!-- Violations of EditorRequired (RZ2012) are turned into true errors -->
  <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings -->
  <WarningsAsErrors>RZ2012</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not yet, no. The best you can do at the moment is to throw an exception in `SetParametersAsync`.

There's a section on optional route parameters on Blazor University that will show how to check if a parameter was passed or not. You simply make it nullable and check it isn't null.
https://blazor-university.com/routing/optional-route-parameters/

Alternatively, if override `SetParametersAsync` you are passed a `ParameterView parameters` parameter, you can use `parameters.TryGetValue` to determine if a parameter was passed, and throw an exception if it wasn't.

But there is currently no way to cause compile-time errors.

Answer (score 2):

As @BenSampica said, gotta wait until .NET 6 for this, but you can use

```
[Parameter]
public string MyString { get; set; } = null!;
```

for now. Won't generate compiler error, but won't let you use it either.